# Comparing arrays: grouping lines from TSV file according to coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I am trying to perform some operations on a file containing a list of TAB separated values, using Python 2.7.2. For more information, the file format is called [BED](http://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQformat.html#format1), and represents a list of genes where each gene is represented by a line. The first three fields of each line represent coordinates. Another field contains a description that might be identical for more than one line.

Within lines with identical description, I need to group together all lines with overlapping coordinates, and somehow name this subgroups unequivocally. The problem is that I would actually need to group all lines that have overlapping coordinates *as a group*, e.g.:

```
chr1    1    3    geneA    1000    +
chr1    3    5    geneA    1000    +
chr1    4    6    geneA    1000    +
chr1    8    9    geneA    1000    +
```

should subgroup the genes as follows:

```
chr1    1    3    geneA    1000    +
chr1    3    5    geneA    1000    +
chr1    4    6    geneA    1000    +
```

and

```
chr1    8    9    geneA    1000    +
```

Eventually the goal would be to output, for each subgroup, a single (new line), e.g.:

```
chr1    1    6    geneA    1000    +
chr1    8    9    geneA    1000    +
```

The value of the first field (chr) is variable, subgroups should be built within lines with the same chr value.

Until now, I tried to solve the problem with this (wrong) approach:

```
#key = description
#values = list of lines (genes) with same description
#self.raw_groups_of_overlapping.items = attribute (dict) containing, given a description, all genes whose description matches the key
#self.picked_cherries = attribute (dict) in which I would like to store, for a given unique identifier, all genes in a specific subgroup (sub-grouping lines according to the aformentioned rule)
#self.__overlappingGenes__(j,k) method evaluating if lines (genes) j and k overlap
for key,values in self.raw_groups_of_overlapping.items():
    for j in values:
        #Remove gene j from list:
        is_not_j = lambda x: x is not j
        other_genes = filter(is_not_j, values) 
        for k in other_genes:
            if self.__overlappingGenes__(j,k):
                intersection = [x for x in j.overlaps_with if x in k.overlaps_with]
                identifier = ''
                for gene in intersection:
                    identifier += gene.chr.replace('chr', '') + str(gene.start) + str(gene.end) + gene.description + gene.strand.replace('\n', '')
                try:
                    self.picked_cherries[identifier].append(j)
                except:
                    self.picked_cherries[identifier] = []
                    self.picked_cherries[identifier].append(j)
                break
```

I understand that somehow I am not considering all genes together, and I would appreciate your input.

Comment: [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)?

Comment: @NightShadeQueen - Thanks, I actually still do not know if  
`itertools.groupby` might be of help. I am afraid I put myself in something too big for my current tasks this time... the main problem should be in `intersection`, but probably I should rewrite the script from scratch to figure things out.